# Flex : A better way to represnt data from a table having large number of columns

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have to give a functionality on one of my pages is like:

I have data which represents data of a row from a table, and table has many columns.

This data has to be edited, and sent back to the server.

I am showing data in a datagrid, which obviously doesnt look good as we always have one row and that too a large row, so user has to use scroll to look for some values.

I want suggestions for this, like what should i use to make it look better and more user friendly.

I could have hard coded things but considering, if tomorrow table schema or xml respnse change it will break.

Any suggestions will be nice.

Comment: can i have the screenshot for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have clearly understood your problem, you have too much information in a row and you would like too be able to see all of your row data in the meantime.

How about creating dynamically, on a row double click by example, a form popup that would display vertically your columns data ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, i need something like vertical data, but in editable format. As I will always have only one row to show and there are some fields editable. So, as per my feeling says a datagrid is not at all the best way to represent that information.

Comment: Hum, I think a datagrid is really fitted to display your data.
Anyway, you can operate differently : construct a vertical form like I said before, or create another datagrid / list component where you will have only one column and multiple rows..